# Set environment variables all over processes in Julia

Tags: environment-variables, julia, hpc, pbs

I'm currently working with Julia (1.0) to run some parallel code on clusters of an HPC. The HPC is managed with PBS. I'm trying to find a way for broadcasting environment variables over all processes, i.e. a way to broadcast a specific list of environment variables automatically in order to have access to them in every Julia worker.

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS ...

export TOTO=toto
julia --machine-file=$PBS_NODEFILE my_script.jl
```

In this example, I will not be able to access to the variable TOTO in each julia worker (via ENV["TOTO"]).

The only way I found to do what I want is to set the variables in my .bashrc but I want this to be script-specific. Another way is to put in my startup.jl file :

```
@everywhere ENV["TOTO"] = $(ENV["TOTO"])
```

But it is not script-specific because I have to know in advance which variables I want to send. If I do a loop over ENV keys then I'll broadcast all the variables and then override variables I don't want to.

I tried to use `DotEnv.jl` but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious way is to set the variables first thing in `script.jl`. You can also put the initialization in a separate file, e.g. `environment.jl`, and load that on all processes with the `-L` flag:

```
julia --machine-file=$PBS_NODEFILE -L environment.jl my_script.jl
```

where `environment.jl` would, in this case, contain

```
ENV["TOTO"] = "toto"
```

etc.